# Manage references globally in MediaWiki (like JebRef)

Tags: reference, mediawiki, wikipedia, centralized

I started a wiki with the MediaWiki Docker container, easy setup.

We have a lot of references and cites and would like to manage them in a centralized way.

Best case:

- see all used references from all sites
- add additional information to the references like notes or (local) file-links
- reuse references/cites from other sites

I tried BiblioPlus, but that's not what I need.
Do you have any tips or ideas?

Comment: Questions seeking for recommendations are off-topic for SO. Please take the [tour], see [ask] and go through the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).